# Euclid's use of antenaresis and Heath's commentary

Tags: euclid, primes

In Book 7, Prop. 1. Euclid uses repeated subtraction to prove that two numbers are relatively prime. As explained [here](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII1.html)  the Greek word for repeated subtraction is "antenaresis". There isn't much information about Antenaresis online. I found [this video](https://youtu.be/Egm6AydHguI?si=BwtFHNmVaamFyLmd) (and [the text mentioned in the video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Io8GnIm-qegGZQwJlbNtb35O8FeLHzEW/view)).

I have two questions. (1) Do you have more information on antenaresis and (2) What does Heath do in his commentary to the mentioned proposition?

Heath's commentary can be found [on page 234 of this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Io8GnIm-qegGZQwJlbNtb35O8FeLHzEW/view):

This is the screen shot:

[image]

I understand what Euclid does but I don't understand Heath's notation.

For instance, how does Heath's notation work for a=85 and b=54?

Comment: Isn't $b$ the divisor of $a$ and $p$ the quotient in the first line? Then $c$ is the remainder, which becomes the divisor of $b$ in the 3rd line? And the process repeats. (Instead of repeated subtraction, the equivalent division is performed. Since multiplication = repeated addition, division = repeated subtraction in modern terms.)

Comment: The WIkipedia page [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) not only describes the repeated subtraction form but also points out that it can be more efficient to do it using division as @MichaelE2 and I both read your screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. So, $b) \;a \; (p$ is $a \div b=p$, remainder $c$. Why is he multiplying $p$ and $b$? Is Heath's notation an old way of doing division?

Comment: The second line $pb$ is subtracted from $a$, leaving $q$ as the remainder. That's how I look at it. Heath is putting the quotient to the (right) side instead of on top (which would be the normal long-division place for me) so that the quotient does not get in the way of the next division.

Comment: Do you know who made up the term "antenaresis"?

Comment: @MichaelE2 From this document https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Io8GnIm-qegGZQwJlbNtb35O8FeLHzEW/view : "The Greek word that is used in both propositions in Euclid’s Elements is ἀνθυφαιρουμένου (un-th-feh-rou-meh-noo). I have no clue what is the origin of this word and have never heard it pronounced in Greek."

Comment: ἀνθυφαιρουμένου is not the same as ἀντεναρεσις (sp?). They both might have the root αἱρέω, to take (away). The first is a participle of the verb ἀνθυφαιρέω. It is formed from anti-/anthi- (against or back/in return— we could use the Latin re- or counter- perhaps); plus hyp-/hyph- (below — Latin sub-); plus -haireo (Latin -tract). So "countersubtracting" or "resubtracting", so to speak, meaning to take away in turn. The second term replaces hyp- by en- (in, on, among). It does not appear in my dictionary. There are several words with the compound prefix anten- (in turn, instead, counter-)....

Comment: ... It seems unlikely the root is ἄρεσις (pleasure, favor). Based on googling, 
"antenaresis" seems to show up in the 21st century. So the I have is, "Is antenaresis a new word used to denote Euclid's algorithm?" A positive answer to this would seem to answer your question.

Comment: The google drive document makes claims about "mainstream" mathematics that are just false. I wouldn't use it as the basis for question. If a question has any merit, a basis for it will exist in another source.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The more common transliteration is *anthyphairesis*, see [Fowler, p. 816](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-06/S0273-0979-1979-14684-6/), [Hewitt](https://new.math.uiuc.edu/public348/paul_hewitt.pdf), etc. However, [Joyce's translation](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVII/propVII1.html) of *Elements* does transliterate it as *antenaresis* instead (in the commentaries). Neither is used in [Heath's translation](https://archive.org/details/thirteenbookseu00heibgoog/page/n308/mode/2up?view=theater).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the Fowler article. So, the sentence "...is continually subtracted in turn from", is stated in Greek in one word as "anthyphairesis"?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is *ἀνθυφαιρουμένου* in the source, *anthyphairesis* and *antenaresis* are liberal nominalizations. Here is the [Greek original](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Euclid/Elements.pdf) split paged with modern translation.

Comment: @Conifold I've read Books VII-IX in Greek. Here's what I think I know: *Antenaresis* is a mistake (by Joyce and others). It is not from a Greek word, does not appear in any source, and is not an alternate form of *anthyphairesis*. It was not used by scholars such as Heath, Knorr, or Fowler, who used the correct term. It does not appear in English before ca. 2000. There is a word, [ἀνταναίρεσις](https://lsj.gr/wiki/ἀνταναίρεσις) (*antanæresis* or *antaneresis*), with transposed e/a (Latin/English form) and a different meaning. (My knowledge is not comprehensive, so I'd welcome any correction.)

Answer (score 2):

```
54 ) 85 ( 1
     54
    ---
     31 ) 54 ( 1
          31
         ---
          23 ) 31 ( 1
               23
              ---
                8 ) 23 ( 2
                    16
                   ---
                     7 ) 8 ( 1
                         7
                        --
                         1
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Euclid's algorithm, is an efficient method for computing the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two integers (numbers)". It is interesting that Euclid does not mention "division", he only talks about repeated substruction. But now, including Heath, this algorithm is assoiated with division.

Comment: @zeynel The terms Euclid, "measures" or "measuring," are translated from two related words, katametreo ("measures out") and metreo ("measures"). They mean in modern terms, "divides,"  sometimes with remainder and sometimes evenly. The statement of prop. VII.1 uses *katametreo* and means divides evenly: "if the number which is left never measures the one before it." The proof uses repeated division with remainder (*metreo*): "And let $CD$ measuring $BF$ leave $FA$ less than itself, and let $AF$ measuring $DG$ leave $GC$ less than itself...." It's Euclid who uses division in the proof.

Comment: @zeynel Here's a screen shot from Weston's [*Arithmetick*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_New_and_Compendious_Treatise_of_Arithm/P1s0L5Z89OIC?hl=en) (1736) p. 93 showing long division in Heath's format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp4Xt.png -- I guess it was the standard format that Heath was taught.

Comment: Even recently, I have seen division arranged this way by people from Europe or Asia.